# sorting string array with int

Tags: c++, arrays, sorting

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void selectionSort (float arr[], int n) {
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        for (j = i+1; j < n; ++j) {
            if (arr[i] > arr[j]) {
                arr[i] = arr[i] + arr[j];
                arr[j] = arr[i] - arr[j];
                arr[i] = arr[i] - arr[j];
            }


        }

    }
}


int main() {
    int n = 3;

    string name[n];
    float arr[n];

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cout << "Name of runner " << i+1 << ": ";
        cin >> name[i];

        cout << "Runner " << i+1 << "'s finishing time: ";
        cin >> arr[i];
        cout << endl;
    }


    selectionSort(arr, n);

    cout << "1st place: " << name[0] << "\t" << arr[0] << endl;
    cout << "2nd place: " << name[1] << "\t" << arr[1] << endl;
    cout << "3rd place: " << name[2] << "\t" << arr[2] << endl;
}
```

So when I enter the name and finishing time, only the finishing time gets sorted into order from fastest to slowest. I need help getting the runner name matched with the finished time.

Comment: Because you are sorting only finishing times, not the names.

Comment: Are you allowed to make an array of a structure that contains both name and time? If you bundle the two together you'll find this to be a much easier-to-solve problem.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of two place holders name[3] and arr[3] try using vector of pairs something like below:

```
std::vector<std::pair<int,string>> RunnerPairVector;
```

Then you can use sort to sort your pairs based on finish time like below

```
std::sort(RunnerPairVector.begin(), RunnerPairVector.end());
```

Comment: This has the added advantage of sorting by name in the event of a tie. Output is more predictable.

Comment: Or use dedicated struct instead of pair: `struct RunnerRecord { std::string name; float timing;};`

Comment: @user4581301 Agreed again it depends on what you are looking for

Answer (score 0):

Sort names also corresponding to their finishing times.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

// Pass name array also to access it..
void selectionSort (string name[], float arr[], int n) {
    int i, j;
    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        for (j = i+1; j < n; ++j) {
            if (arr[i] > arr[j]) {
                arr[i] = arr[i] + arr[j];
                arr[j] = arr[i] - arr[j];
                arr[i] = arr[i] - arr[j];
                // Swap names also corresponding to their finishing times.
                string temp = name[i];
                name[i] = name[j];
                name[j] = temp;
            }


        }

    }
}


int main() {
    int n = 3;

    string name[n];
    float arr[n];

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cout << "Name of runner " << i+1 << ": ";
        cin >> name[i];

        cout << "Runner " << i+1 << "'s finishing time: ";
        cin >> arr[i];
        cout << endl;
    }


    selectionSort(name, arr, n);

    cout << "1st place: " << name[0] << "\t" << arr[0] << endl;
    cout << "2nd place: " << name[1] << "\t" << arr[1] << endl;
    cout << "3rd place: " << name[2] << "\t" << arr[2] << endl;
}
```

Comment: Can you please explain how the sorting works for the time? Like arr[I] = arr[I] + arr[j]. What does that mean?

Comment: The line you mentioned and the 2 lines below this one are meant for swapping the a[i] and a[j]. You can use other method also like I did for strings using the temp variable.

Comment: Please  have a look at this to understand more about the selection sort algorithm you are using : https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/selection-sort/

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing wrong here is that you are sorting the time array but not making respective changes to the name array. so you can pass the name array also along with time array and when you swap the time, at the same time swap the corresponding names. something like this..

```
void selectionSort(float arr[], string name[], int n) {
  int i, j;
  string temp;
  for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    for (j = i + 1; j < n; ++j) {
      if (arr[i] > arr[j]) {
        arr[i] = arr[i] + arr[j];
        arr[j] = arr[i] - arr[j];
        arr[i] = arr[i] - arr[j];
        //name swapping
        temp = name[i];
        name[i] = name[j];
        name[j] = temp;
      }

    }

  }
}
```

and one more thing is that your function not returning this changed array. so either you return this changed array or make this time and name array globally accessible.